# How to access already deployed Smart Contract using Java?

Tags: tokens, web3j, java

I would like to get information about token. For example total supply and so on. For this I need the contract. However what is the way to actually load it/access it from Java?

Checking examples in languages such as python, it seems trivial:

```
contract_address = 'CONTRACT_ADDRESS' 

abi = json.loads(abiJson)

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=abi)

totalSupply = contract.functions.totalSupply().call()
```

However how to actually do this using Java? Do I need to generate .abi file and then compile it to java? This way, wouldn't I need to recompile the project everytime I wanted to find info about another contract?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

[Web3j](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) provides you with the ability to generate Java wrappers from ABI files for Solidity smart contracts.
You can do so in different ways, mainly:

- [Use web3j-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-gradle-plugin) or [web3j-maven-plugin](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-maven-plugin);
- Use [web3j-CLI](https://github.com/web3j/web3j-cli) to generate the wrappers.

For your case, you can use the [web3j-codegen](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/codegen/src/main/java/org/web3j/codegen/SolidityFunctionWrapperGenerator.java) module to generate the wrappers. Then, [load the generated class dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6219855/11529598).

Since you only need a set of predefined methods that follow ERC20 standard or similar. This might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

- Run task(generateContractWrappers), wrapper contracts will be generated under build/generated/sources/web3j/ERC20.java
- Generate contract instance using above wrapper

```
    ERC20 contractInstance=ERC20.load(String contractAddress, Web3j web3j, Credentials credentials, ContractGasProvider contractGasProvider)
   //contract gas provider can be created from DefaultGasProvider or StaticGasProvider
   //Credentials credential=Credentials.create(privatekey);
```

- Call contract functions

```
    BigInteger totalSupply=contractInstance.totalSupply().send();
```